# How can I delay s.t call in adobe DTM?

Tags: javascript, tags, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I have created one event based rule-

In adobe analytics portion I have set s.t call but how can I delay this call - “s.t call”

Here i have attached one screenshot where i actually set.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke700.png)

Answer (score 1):

DTM does not currently offer a way to delay the `s.t` (or `s.tl`) trigger in **Event Based Rules** (EBR), so you will have to write your own javascript that ultimately makes the `s.t` call.

Since your screenshot shows the Adobe Analytics (AA) section in your **EBR**, it sounds like you have AA setup as a **Tool** in DTM. DTM lets you reference the AA `s` object within the custom code section of the AA section of a tool, but it doesn't have an official way to get a reference of AA `s` object outside of that scope.

So in order to achieve this, you have to put the `s` object into the global (`window`) scope in the **Tool** config.  You can do this by adding a line in the custom code box of the AA **Tool** config

`window.s = s;`

(or if you changed the namespace to something else in the tool config, use that instead).

Next, a note about using `this` - I noticed in your screenshot for **Page Name** you have `%this.getAttribute(data-search-pagename)%`.  Because you want to delay the `s.t` call, whatever you are doing (e.g. a `setTimeout`, popping it inside some ajax callback function, etc.) will almost certainly take you out of the scope where `this` properly references the element the **EBR** is based off of, so you will no longer be able to use `this` to populate the page name.

To get around `this`, go to the **Conditions** section of the **EBR**.  Under **Rule Conditions** > **Criteria**, choose **Data : Custom**.  In the **Custom** code box, you can add the following:

```
_satellite.setVar('data_search_pagename',this.getAttribute('data-search-pagename'));
return true;
```

The above will push the `data-search-pagename` attribute value to a **Data Element** named 'data_search_pagename' (or name it whatever you want, according to your conventions). The `return true;` part will always make this condition true, so that it is "invisible" to your rule and not actually affect whether or not the rule should trigger.

Finally, in the **EBR**, you will *not* use the AA tool section (choose the **disabled** option in that section).  Instead, you will need to create and add your code in the **Javascript / Third Party Tags** section of the **EBR**.  You will need to set whatever AA vars you had in the AA section as regular javascript variables, and for the **Data Element** `%data_element%` syntax, instead use the `_satellite.getVar('data_element')` javascript syntax .

I'm not sure what kind of delay you are looking to do, but here's a 100ms delay as an example (based on what is shown in your screenshot):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var s = window.s;
    s.pageName = _satellite.getVar('data_search_pagename');
    s.channel = _satellite.getVar('util_channel');
    s.t();
},100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of these types of events on your site where the page view call needs to be more controlled, I would recommend using a direct call rule and aborting the initial AA PV call. In fact, it is common to create a "global page load" rule for single page applications (SPA) or for when you are waiting for ajax to return search results - for example

Here's a jQuery example of using a direct call rule within a search results page rule that will fire after ajax has completed and returned:

```
Javascript: jQuery - wait for callback and call DC rule

/* Ajax Detection on SRP */ 
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    _satellite.track('my_pageView_rule_here')

})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, wholesale suppressing the initial page view call from DTM and then triggering it yourself in a direct call rule is a good approach for controlling the `s.t` call timing for *initial page load* tracking.  Not entirely sure that's applicable here though, since OP is using an Event Based Rule? OP should clarify, since this would be a simpler solution in general, if that is indeed what he's going for..

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, if you have multiple occasions where the page view needs to be controlled (ie waiting for ajax search results, etc) you may want to consider a broader solution.